# Segmented Control in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-button

We all know segmented control that is IOS but not in android. So I have an application that need something like that. For example let suppose I have a list of students and teacher marks the student either absent or present.  and on click of each option there is a service call . for this I am using a library which is as follows:

> compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'

As I told you I have a list of students so in list I have the following case;

Case 1: If the teacher review the attendance the of last day , I fetch a list of students that are either absent or present. So on this , the segmented control that I am using in list fires the onCheckChangedlistener which run the code which is also performing some task , where as I only want to perform the task only when user change the listener. In short listener should not fire when I change any check pragmatically. and Also it fires the onCheckChangedListener multiple times. which creates problem for me :

So I have couple of question:

1) what can be used in android in place of the Segmented control library as I stated above.

2) what is possible workaround for this problem. I tried using flag but I am working in getview of listview.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good library in response to what you achieve. I have used this and found the similar problem. So hence by putting flag , and making a raw check over it does a work for me . But As you are using list, i think you can not achieve what you are looking for.

I will suggest to use the radio button to get the check or you can make your custom control like [this](http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2011/09/segmented-button-control-in-android.html)  and see [this](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol) library

Comment: that tutorial is great , i will follow this